# Local storage is empty

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I created an SPA that uses oauth, it seams to work but there is an issue if I open the app for the first time.

Then local storage seams to be cleared.

My application, is written in vue but it seams to me that this is not a vue issue.

This is my code that does the redirect.

```
    let nonce = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        nonce += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
    }
    document.cookie = nonce;
    localStorage.setItem('nonce', nonce);
    windows.location.href = 'my-oauth-url...';
```

This is my code that validates the nonce after the redirect:

```
    if (to.path.includes('/callback')) {
        const urlSearch = new URLSearchParams(to.hash);
        const nonce = extractResponseNonce(urlSearch);
        alert('stored nonce ' + localStorage.getItem('nonce'));
        alert('cookie ' + document.cookie)
        console.log('stored nonce ' + localStorage.getItem('nonce'))
        console.log('state ' + store.state.nonce)
        console.log('extracted nonce ' + nonce)
        // using document.cookie works
        if (localStorage.getItem('nonce') != nonce) {
            next('/error/nonceError')
            return
        }
}
```

If I use the localstoreage to compare the nonce I get null, and go to the nonce error page.

If I redo the login process again after that everthing works.

I checked with the alerts that the value is realy set before doing the first redirect.

PS: I always use the private mode of firefox for testing this application (I don't think that this should matter).

Do you have an idea why localstorage returns null to me but the cookie is filled correctly?

Comment: `windows.location.href = 'my-oauth-url...';` same host, right?

Comment: Does it work in the normal mode of firefox

Comment: No, an idp like microsoft.

Comment: `console.log('extracted nonce [' + nonce + ']')` if you do that before you redirect and after, is the string EXACTLY the same between the `[]`

Comment: @SandilRanasinghe yes it works. I gues that has the same reason, why i works in private mode at second try.

Comment: @Bravo if I get the nonce from local storage it is null, on the seconds attempt it is exactly the same. If I use a cookie it also works on the first attempt.

Comment: oh, right - that's interesting. which browser does this nonsense?

Comment: @Bravo Chromium behaves the same.

Comment: Oh, weird, I have a PWA that uses localStorage and never have an issue in private mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the transition between http and https.

I just called http in my browser, and because it was a test setup I did not do a redirect to https.
But the redirect-URL back to my frontend uses https, then the local-storage was empty because the url changed.
The cookie on the other hand doesn't mind about http or https it's just pinned at the domain.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not finding anything in local storage, that could also be because, **you are just in the folder of local storage**.

***Inside the local storage folder*** in developer console, ***there will be a file with your domain name, where you will find all key value pairs stored***.